# ng-change not working ,how can i use ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want get the the team_id as well as team name but ng-change not working here . Suggest me a better way to get out this problem.

```
<th style="width:20%">
<select 
  style="height: 40px;
         font-size: 12px;
         width: 100%;
         border-radius: 3px;
         border: 1px solid #dfe3e9;
         background: url(../image/select-icon.png) 100% no-repeat !important;
         padding-left: 8px;
         -webkit-appearance: none;
         -moz-appearance: none;
         appearance: none;
         padding-right: 23px;"
  ng-model="team_selected"
  name="team_selected"
  required=""
  ng-change="selected_team(team_selected)">
  <option value="" disabled="" selected="selected">Select Team</option>
  <option
    value="{{teams.team_id}}"
    ng-repeat="teams in teamavailable track by teams.team_id">
    {{teams.team_name}}
  </option>
</select>
</th>
```

Comment: your selected_team method is not getting called right?

Comment: add the ng-change to the select not to the option

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ng-options as shown below code and then check your ng-change whether it is working or not.

```
<select ng-model="team_selected" name="team_selected" required ng-change="selected_team(team_selected)" ng-options="team.team_id as team.team_name for team in teamavailable track by team.team_id" >
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="selected">Select Team </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Setting ng-options on select create multiple selects

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-options` and use your team object as options value, so you can pass whole object or desired attributes to function.

Here is the [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UbK7YFuvJu7ix7NCjizn)...

```
<select ng-model="selected_team" 
        ng-change="selectTeam(selected_team.id, selected_team.name)"
        ng-options="team.name for team in teams">
  <option value="" disabled="" selected="selected">Select Team </option>
</select>
```